# Lovecraftian WW2 sci fi novel with three Nazi villains who had wires coming out of their heads, connected to batteries, that gave them their powers

Tags: story-identification, books, time-travel, nazis

I'm trying to remember a book I read. This would have been around 2017.

- I believe it was part of a trilogy.
- It had a Lovecraft vibe; the bad guys were at least 3 Nazis, 2 of whom were brother and sister. They had wires coming out of their heads that connected to batteries and gave them their powers. The brother could move through matter, the sister could predict the future, and the other one had immense physical strength.
- The hero had a son who had no soul and cried all the time.

I think there was also a time-travel element to it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This sounds a lot like Ian Tregillis' trilogy that started with *Bitter Seeds* and followed with *Coldest War* and *Necessary Evil*.  *Definitely* a Lovecraft vibe -- British warlocks fighting Nazi warlocks in a war where nothing was held back. Nasty!

I recall kids run by a Nazi warlock who had wires in their heads.  (OTOH, "the hero had a son who had no soul and cried all the time" rings no bells at all.)

The third book involved paratime travel.

The books were published by Tor in 2010, 2012, and 2013, so the dates are a bit early.

Comment: That's the one - thank you! One of those books I remember reading and feeling disturbed by, but still feel like revisiting.

Comment: I was disturbed enough that while I bought it, I'm pretty sure I never read the third volume!